# Disable menu highlight when pressing shortcut key

Tags: objective-c, nsmenu

I would like to disable the Application "menu highlight" that happens when you press a shortcut key assigned to an NSMenuItem that belongs to the specific menu in question.

The issue is that in the application you use the keyboard quite a bit and having the menus becoming highlighted all the time becomes a bit annoying but I still want to have the menus (including the shortcuts) there as it shows the user which actions that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a custom NSMenuItem subclass and start using that custom class instead of NSMenuItem.

In this class you should override this method:

```
- (BOOL)isHighlighted
{
    return NO;
}
```

This way you will not have the menu item highlighted.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
[item setOnStateImage: item.offStateImage];
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work. isHighlighted method will never get called (I also tried to just implement isHidden to see that the code work and that behaves as expected)

Comment: Doing setOnStateImage didn't help as well

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that we are talking about the same thing but here is the highlight I want to disable https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5205843/menu_highlight.png (this is what happens when I press a key with an item inside the view menu)

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand. Permission to what?

Comment: Sorry, I posted that comment for mistake.

Answer (score 0):

FFR: Look up the following methods in the docs:

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem
```

Will work for both selecting the menu item and the associated command key.

Within your NSDocument provide a body for `validateMenuItem`
such as,

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem 
{
    SEL theAction = [menuItem action];
    if (theAction == @selector(openPreferencesPanel:)) {
        return !_isCurrentlyModal;                   //A BOOL in MyDocument
    }
    return [super validateMenuItem:menuItem];           // Keep this for proper cut, paste, etc validation
}
```

In your case, the above selector might be `highlight:`. Check the nib/xib and inspect it. It might be attached to the First Responder. Copy the method name.

Also have a gander at for more general items (buttons, etc) and also includes menu items.

```
- (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id <NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem>)anItem
```